# OOP Hangman Game

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, hangman

My daughter and I are trying to teach ourselves Python and OOP. We wrote a hangman game, and we'd really appreciate some feedback. Are we heading in the right direction? How could we improve it? Anything that makes a Python programmer go "ouch"? Anything that makes an OOP expert cringe? All sorts of questions occur to us. For example, should we be instantiating classes when there is only one instance? Feel free to be brutal! We've posted it as a repl here:
https://replit.com/@scripta/Hangman#main.py

Changed the invoking functionality into a class "Game" as per ASM's suggestion.

A huge thanks for the time and effort that went into commenting on the code. With apologies for having initially changed the code in this initial post (see above), here is a new post with most of the suggestions acted upon:
[OOP Hangman Game - amended code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/266049/oop-hangman-game-amended-code)

```
import random

class Word:

    def __init__(self):
        words = ("foxglove", "captain", "oxygen", "microwave", "rhubarb")
        self._word = random.choice(words)
        self.letters_in_word=set(self._word)

    @property
    def word(self):
        return self._word

    def progress(self, guesses):
        # create string of underscores and guessed letters to show progress to guessing word
        progress_string= ""
        for char in self.word:
            if guesses.guessed(char):
                progress_string= progress_string+" "+char+" "
            else:
                progress_string= progress_string +" _ "
        return(progress_string)

    def guessed(self, guesses):
        letters_guessed = self.letters_in_word.intersection(guesses.guesses_made)
        if letters_guessed == self.letters_in_word:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class Guesses:

    def __init__(self):
        # guesses holds all guesses made (wrong or right)
        self.guesses_made = set()

    def guessed(self,char):
        if char in self.guesses_made:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def record(self,guess,word):
        # All valid guesses (wrong or right) are added to the guesses set
        self.guesses_made.add(guess)
        if not guess in word.letters_in_word:
            Gallows.record_bad_guess()

    def made(self):
        # to sort the set of guesses made we need to cast it to a list
        guesses_list= list(self.guesses_made)
        guesses_list.sort()
        guesses_string=""
        #comma separate the guesses
        for char in guesses_list:
            guesses_string= guesses_string+char+","
        return guesses_string

class Gallows:

    _bad_guesses=0

    gallows_images = ("      \n      \n        \n         \n        \n__________",
                      "      \n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/   \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/  |\n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |   |   \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|   \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |      \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  /   \n_|________",
                      " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  / \\\n_|________",)

    @classmethod
    def record_bad_guess(cls):
        cls._bad_guesses +=1

    @classmethod
    def hanged(cls):
        if cls._bad_guesses >= len(cls.gallows_images)-1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @classmethod
    def draw(cls):
        return cls.gallows_images[cls._bad_guesses]

class Game:

    def get_letter(self, guesses):
        while True:
            char= input("\nPlease enter your guess: ")
            if len(char)<1:
                print ("You didn't choose a letter!")
            elif len(char)!=1:
                print ("One letter at a time!")
            elif not char.isalpha():
                print ("Alphabetic characters only!")
            elif guesses.guessed (char):
                print ("You already guessed that letter")
            else:
                break       
        return (char)

    def display_progress(self, target, gallows, guesses):
        print("\n",target.progress(guesses)) 
        print(gallows.draw())
        print("\nUsed: \n",guesses.made())

    def play(self):
        target= Word()
        guesses= Guesses()
        gallows= Gallows()
        while True:
            guess= self.get_letter(guesses)
            guesses.record(guess,target)
            self.display_progress(target, gallows, guesses)
            if target.guessed(guesses):
                print("\nYou win, well done")
                break
            if gallows.hanged():
                print ("\nI win. The word was:",target.word)
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game= Game()
    game.play()
```

Comment: It's not an answer neither the code review but I recommend writing unit tests for your code which helps to decompose your code better while giving insights on the dependency management. 
 
Quick over view, OOP implementation is good enough. You have separated different entities with their roles which is the most important part in OOAD. The main invoking functionality can also be changed into a class to complete it.

Comment: We've created a class "Game" to run the game. Is that what you meant? Will look at adding unit tests.

Comment: @scripta questions should not be modified based on answers. It should be left as is, because it could make certain comments lose meaning. If, after receiving feedback, you'd like to update your code and have it reviewed, you should post another question, and add a link to it here (maybe even a link to this question in the new one).

Comment: I don't know much about the technical aspects of python, but that looks like pretty code to me. I have three suggestions, which have nothing to do with your coding: 1) present a game introduction; 2) get the words from a file containing a list of many more words; and 3) introduce scorekeeping and a display of scores, wins and losses, at the end. That will make it more interesting and competitive. (I first wrote a hangman game like that as a DOS batch file and I have one written in bash on my web server now.)

Comment: @AnitShresthaManandhar recomending unit-testing for a private hobby project is like building a sewer system and high-voltage transformator for your garden-shed

Comment: @clockw0rk: True...but if you're doing it for the purpose of learning the language and practicing best practices, it's not a horrible idea. Lots of things that are overkill in regular use can be beneficial for education. That said, I wouldn't recommend unit tests for this purpose, either. ;)

Answer (score 8):

From the first looks, quite nice.  I have mostly just a few smaller
concerns:

- Consistency matters for readers, so should be either `x = y`, `x= y`
  or `x =y` (or any variant really).  Using
  [an autoformatter](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is of
  course easier than doing that manually, but otherwise I'd generally go
  for the first variant.
- For `words`:  if you have a sequence, use a `list`, not a `tuple`.
  It's clearer and fits the purpose better, e.g. if you were to add new
  elements to the list of words it only works with `list`, because
  `tuple`'s are immutable.
- Negating `in` can be done with `not in`, which reads more naturally.
- The pattern `if x == y: return True else: return False` is not making
  use of the fact that `x == y` *already* returns a boolean value - it
  can simply be replaced by the much shorter `return x == y`.
- Some members have an underscore, some don't - unless you strife for a
  very hard border between private and public properties I'd pick one
  and stick with it, if you go with the underscores, then just provide
  `@property` accessors for them if necessary.
- Each of the images could probably be easier to read by using
  multi-line strings (`"""these ones"""`).
- If you want to get into list comprehensions, `made`'s way of
  formatting can be a little bit simpler via `str`'s `join` method,
  e.g. `",".join(self.guessed_made)`.
- `sorted` can be simpler than `list` followed by `sort`,
  e.g. `sorted(self.guesses_made)` does what you think it does.

Structurally, the next thing I saw was that `Guesses` uses the `Gallows`
class, not an object, while in `play_hangman.py` it's being constructed
as an object and also used like one.  I'd pick one and stick with it.
Since it's intended to be more OOP, right, I'd go with dropping the
class methods and make it an actual object, that seems cleaner and
at least in theory would allow for better testing anyway.

Wrt. an overall `Game` class:  if you want to do it for learning
reasons, sure, but really in Python at least it's fine to have
standalone functions too.  Of course you can do things like mocking all
your dependencies that way, but even just having `play_game` take
`target`, `guesses` and `gallows` as parameters would still allow you to
do that.  Edit:  And I'm not gonna follow that edit since I was already typing this out before.

`play_hangman.py`:

```py
import hangman


def get_letter(guesses):
    while True:
        char = input("\nPlease enter your guess: ")
        if len(char) < 1:
            print("You didn't choose a letter!")
        elif len(char) != 1:
            print("One letter at a time!")
        elif not char.isalpha():
            print("Alphabetic characters only!")
        elif guesses.guessed(char):
            print("You already guessed that letter")
        else:
            break
    return char


def play_game():
    target = hangman.Word()
    guesses = hangman.Guesses()
    gallows = hangman.Gallows()
    while True:
        guess = get_letter(guesses)
        guesses.record(gallows, guess, target)
        print("\n", target.progress(guesses))
        print(gallows.draw())
        print("\nUsed: \n", guesses.made())
        if target.guessed(guesses):
            print("\nYou win, well done")
            break
        if gallows.hanged():
            print("\nI win. The word was:", target.word)
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_game()
```

`hangman.py`:

```py
import random


class Word:
    def __init__(self):
        words = ["foxglove", "captain", "oxygen", "microwave", "rhubarb"]
        self.word = random.choice(words)
        self.letters_in_word = set(self.word)

    def progress(self, guesses):
        # create string of underscores and guessed letters to show progress to guessing word
        return "  ".join(char if guesses.guessed(char) else "_" for char in self.word)

    def guessed(self, guesses):
        letters_guessed = self.letters_in_word & guesses.guesses_made
        return letters_guessed == self.letters_in_word


class Guesses:
    def __init__(self):
        # guesses holds all guesses made (wrong or right)
        self.guesses_made = set()

    def guessed(self, char):
        return char in self.guesses_made

    def record(self, gallows, guess, word):
        # All valid guesses (wrong or right) are added to the guesses set
        self.guesses_made.add(guess)
        if guess not in word.letters_in_word:
            gallows.record_bad_guess()

    def made(self):
        return ",".join(sorted(self.guesses_made))


class Gallows:
    gallows_images = (
        "      \n      \n        \n         \n        \n__________",
        "      \n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/   \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/  |\n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |   |   \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|   \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |      \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  /   \n_|________",
        " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  / \\\n_|________",
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self._bad_guesses = 0

    def record_bad_guess(self):
        self._bad_guesses += 1

    def hanged(self):
        return self._bad_guesses >= len(self.gallows_images) - 1

    def draw(self):
        return self.gallows_images[self._bad_guesses]
```

Comment: Note that, about your _unless you [strive] for a very hard border between private and public properties_, there's not really such a thing in Python.

Comment: Regarding your comment about `words` being a `list`, I'd argue a `tuple` fits the purpose better, as it is being used a fixed number of possibilities that will not be updated at runtime

Answer (score 5):

(Some of these points have already been covered by the answer already posted, but I was already halfway through writing this when it appeared.)

---

This looks like a fun programme, and has got a lot of great stuff in it! This isn't a full review by any means, but here's a few small tips for improving your code:

**1. Move the `words` variable out of the `Word.__init__` method.**

This variable is an arbitrary constant that isn't altered during execution of the program. You should try to minimise the extent to which such constant values are buried in the middle of your code, so that it is obvious where they are and easy to modify their values should you find yourself editing your code in the future. It's also good practice to give them ALL_CAPS names, which is the convention for constant values that never change. (Your `Gallows.gallows_images` attribute should be renamed as `Gallows.GALLOWS_IMAGES` for the same reason.)

Constant values should either go at the top of a module in the global namespace, or at the top of a class in the class namespace. In this case, I'd put it at the top of the class:

```
import random

class Word:
    WORDS = ("foxglove", "captain", "oxygen", "microwave", "rhubarb")

    def __init__(self):
        self._word = random.choice(self.WORDS)
        self.letters_in_word = set(self._word)
```

**2. Keeping to the [PEP8 style guide](https://pep8.org/) will make your code more readable for other people.**

In particular, there are lots of places in your code where you don't have spaces around operators such as `+` and `=`, which I personally find quite hard to read.

**3. Using F-strings is a more pythonic way of concatenating strings**

In your `Word.progress` method, you start with an empty string, and add values to it iteratively using the `+` operator. You could make this more readable by using the `+=` operator to add characters to your string, and by using F-strings to reduce your other uses of the `+` operator:

```
class Word:
    # <--- snip --->

    def progress(self, guesses):
        # create string of underscores and guessed letters to show progress to guessing word
        progress_string = ""
        for char in self.word:
            if guesses.guessed(char):
                progress_string += f" {char} "
            else:
                progress_string += " _ "
        return(progress_string)
```

You could even use Python's ternary operator to shorten this even further:

```
class Word:
    # <--- snip --->

    def progress(self, guesses):
        # create string of underscores and guessed letters to show progress to guessing word
        progress_string = ""
        for char in self.word:
            progress_string += f" {char} " if guesses.guessed(char) else " _ "
        return(progress_string)
```

Or use the `str.join` method and a generator expression to make it into a one-liner!

```
class Word:
    # <--- snip --->

    def progress(self, guesses):
        # create string of underscores and guessed letters to show progress to guessing word
        return "".join((f" {char} " if guesses.guessed(char) else " _ ") for char in self.word)
```

**4. Your methods that return `bool` values can be simplified**

Your `Word.guessed` method can be simplified like so:

```
class Word:
    # <--- snip --->

    def guessed(self, guesses):
        return bool(self.letters_in_word.difference(guesses.guesses_made))
```

Your `Guesses.guessed` method can be simplified like so:

```
class Guesses:
    # <--- snip --->

    def guessed(self, char):
        return char in self.guesses_made
```

And your `Gallows.hanged` method can also be shortened to one line:

```
class Gallows:
    # <-- snip -->

    @classmethod
    def hanged(cls):
        return cls._bad_guesses >= (len(cls.gallows_images) - 1)
```

It's a little unclear to me why your `Gallows._bad_guesses` attribute is marked as private, by the way. I think it would be fine to have it as a public `Gallows.bad_guesses` attribute. It's also a bit of a code smell to have a class where every method is a `classmethod` — for a more comprehensive refactoring of your `Gallows` class, I'd take a look at @ferada's answer.

I also agree with @ferada that there's no real need for your `Game` class, as none of its functions keep track of internal state at all. If your code is purely procedural, it's more pythonic to have your functions in the global namespace rather than creating objects for the sake of objects (this is very different to other languages such as Java).

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review!

If you just started learning, it seems decently good. Here are a few comments in no particular order:

Edit: After posting the answer, I've seen most it not all the points below have already being covered in other answers written while I was writing mine. Still, I will leave it here as it might be useful

- In general, have a read at [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is a general style guide widely followed by the community. For example, you are not using consistent spacing:

```py
# No slace on the left of the assignment
progress_string= progress_string+" "+char+" "
# Space on the left
self.guesses_made = set()
```

- Regarding OOP design, `Gallows` is poorly designed. It is used as a king of namespace, having all methods being classmethods, it has class properties, but it is also instatiated. It should simply be a class with its properties and its methods.
- Useage of bools:

```py
if condition:
  return True
else:
  return False
```

Can be changed to:

```py
retun condition
```

For example, the `guessed` method in `Guesses`

- The `Guesses#made` method can be simplified:

```py
sorted_guesses = list(self.guesses_made).sort()
return ",".joint(sorted_guesses)
```

- `Guesses` is just a wrapper around a set, so it probably should not be a class, and just a property in the game object. The `Guesses#made` method could be a method a `Game` method. The `Guesses#record` method should not depend on `Gallows` (it doesn't really make sense), so it its just a `set#add`.
- To me, method names should have meaning all by themselves. For example, `made` does not tell me anything unless I read it as `Guesses#made`. So it probably should be renamed to something like `made_guesses`.
- `word`, `guesses` and `gallows` should be `Game`'s properties created upon initialization. They could also be created on a method called `init` or `reset` that was called upon initialization. This would allow restarting a game in a more explicit way (currently you could just call `play` twice)