# OOP Hangman Game - amended code

Tags: python, object-oriented

This code was originally posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/265940/oop-hangman-game?noredirect=1#comment525419_265940). An exercise into learning OOP and Python. A huge thanks for the time and effort that @ferada @Alex Waygood @m-alorda and others put into commenting on it.

You can run it as a repl here:
https://replit.com/@scripta/Hangman#main.py

Most of the issues raised have been acted on. A couple of things are still to be addressed.

**Quality of partitioning into objects:**

Should there be a “Game” object or should the driving logic be left as standalone procedures? There seems a need to group the driving logic (and supporting functions), either as a separate module or an object. Does it really matter which?

What about the Gallows class? In a way the gallows is a record of bad guesses. However it has the merit of being familiar in terms of the game. Should guesses be a property of a Game object?

How to judge what makes a good object? Simplicity? Familiarity in terms of subject? ...? Any thoughts?

**Method naming:**

Object.method() seemed to leave room for a succinct and natural English like approach when invoking methods such as
if target.guessed()...
That can make the method names confusing when read in isolation (in a class definition). Anyone else want to chip in on that?

Hope nothing was missed. Now that the code’s been cleaned up, any other comments?

play_hangman.py (uses objects Word, Guesses and Gallows in hangman.py)

```
import hangman

def get_letter(guesses):
    while True:
        char= input("\nPlease enter your guess: ")
        if len(char) < 1:
            print ("You didn't choose a letter!")
        elif len(char)!= 1:
            print ("One letter at a time!")
        elif not char.isalpha():
            print ("Alphabetic characters only!")
        elif guesses.guessed (char):
            print ("You already guessed that letter")
        else:
            break
    return (char)

def display_progress(target, gallows, guesses):
    print("\n",target.progress(guesses))
    print(gallows.draw())
    print("\nUsed: \n",guesses.made())

def play_game():
    target = hangman.Word()
    guesses = hangman.Guesses()
    gallows = hangman.Gallows()
    while True:
        guess = get_letter(guesses)
        guesses.record(guess,target,gallows)
        display_progress(target, gallows, guesses)
        if target.guessed(guesses):
            print("\nYou win, well done")
            break
        if gallows.hanged():
            print ("\nI win. The word was:",target.word)
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_game()
```

hangman.py

```
import random

class Word:

    WORDS = ("foxglove", "captain", "oxygen", "microwave", "rhubarb")

    def __init__(self):
        self._word = random.choice(self.WORDS)
        self.letters_in_word = set(self._word)

    @property
    def word(self):
        return self._word

    def progress(self, guesses):
        # create string of underscores and guessed letters to show progress to guessing word
        progress_string = ""
        for char in self.word:
            if guesses.guessed(char):
                progress_string += f" {char} "
            else:
                progress_string += " _ "
        return(progress_string)

    def guessed(self, guesses):
        letters_guessed= self.letters_in_word.intersection(guesses.guesses_made)
        return letters_guessed == self.letters_in_word

class Guesses:

    def __init__(self):
        # guesses holds all guesses made (wrong or right)
        self.guesses_made = set()

    def guessed(self,char):
        return char in self.guesses_made

    def record(self,guess,word,gallows):
        # All valid guesses (wrong or right) are added to the guesses set
        self.guesses_made.add(guess)
        if guess not in word.letters_in_word:
            gallows.record_bad_guess()

    def made(self):
        guesses_list = sorted(self.guesses_made)
        #comma separate the guesses
        guesses_string = ",".join(guesses_list)
        return guesses_string

class Gallows:

    bad_guesses = 0

    GALLOWS_IMAGES= ("      \n      \n        \n         \n        \n__________",
                     "      \n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/   \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/  |\n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |   |   \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|   \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |      \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  /   \n_|________",
                     " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  / \\\n_|________",)

    def record_bad_guess(self):
        self.bad_guesses += 1

    def hanged(self):
        return self.bad_guesses >= len(self.GALLOWS_IMAGES) -1

    def draw(self):
        return self.GALLOWS_IMAGES[self.bad_guesses]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great improvement on the original code -- well done! A few points:

**1. Still not [PEP8](https://pep8.org/)-compliant :(**

There's still lots of places in your code where you don't have spaces around operators (sorry, it's a bit of a bugbear of mine!), and a few other PEP8 breaches. `elif len(char)!= 1` should be `elif len(char) != 1`; `guesses.guessed (char)` should be `guesses.guessed(char)`; `print("\n",target.progress(guesses))` should be `print("\n", target.progress(guesses))`, etc. If you use an IDE like PyCharm, this will help you a lot with this, as it will automatically flag parts of your code that don't conform to PEP8.

Another thing that you could consider adding to your code that would make your code more readable for other people is docstrings, which are hugely valuable.

**2. Is a `Game` class necessary?**

Your code looks much more logical to me as it is now, without the `Game` class. I probably wouldn't call the main file `play_hangman.py`, however -- you should probably call the directory that both files are in `hangman`, and call the file that's currently called `play_hangman.py` `main.py`. Files called `main.py` are commonly understood by python users to be the main entrypoint to a python project.

With regard to your broader question about how you should conceptualise objects in object-oriented programming... it depends. One of the wonderful things about Python is how easy it makes it to combine elements from multiple programming paradigms. In some scripts I find myself writing extremely procedural code, in others extremely object-oriented code, and in others extremely functional code. In this case, a certain amount of object-oriented style makes sense for the project, but there's no need to go overboard. To program pythonically is to prioritise elegance and simplicity above any "rules" associated with one or another programming paradigm. You don't *need* a `Game` class here, and it doesn't really make your code more efficient, elegant, or easier to understand... so why have one?

**3. Is a `Gallows` class necessary?**

I think you're correct that your `Gallows` class, as it is, isn't currently doing much work. However, as you say, it's easy to understand what a `Gallows` class might do. If anything, the idea of a `Guesses` class feels slightly harder to wrap my head around. I think I might combine your `Guesses` and `Gallows` classes like so:

```
class Gallows:
    """The `Gallows` class records the guesses you've made,
    and delivers upon you a slow and painful death
    should you make too many incorrect guesses.
    """

    GALLOWS_IMAGES = (
         "      \n      \n        \n         \n        \n__________",
         "      \n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/   \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/  |\n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |   |   \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|   \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |      \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  /   \n_|________",
         " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  / \\\n_|________"
    )

    GALLOWS_IMAGES_LEN = len(GALLOWS_IMAGES)

    def __init__(self):
        # `guesses_made` holds all guesses made (wrong or right)
        self.guesses_made = set()
        self.incorrect_guesses = 0

    def character_already_guessed(self, char):
        return char in self.guesses_made

    def record_guess(self, guess, word):
        # All valid guesses (wrong or right) are added to the `guesses_made` set
        self.guesses_made.add(guess)
        if guess not in word.letters_in_word:
            self.incorrect_guesses += 1

    def all_guesses_made(self):
        guesses_list = sorted(self.guesses_made)
        # comma-separate the guesses
        guesses_string = ",".join(guesses_list)
        return guesses_string

    def hanged(self):
        return self.bad_guesses >= self.GALLOWS_IMAGES_LEN - 1

    def draw(self):
        return self.GALLOWS_IMAGES[self.bad_guesses]
```

If you go down this route, you'll need to make sure you update the file that's currently called `play_hangman.py` so that it doesn't hold any references to a `Guesses` class that no longer exists.

**4. Places you could consider taking the project next**

I'd say the main outstanding issue with your project is that there are only a few words that the word you're trying to guess could be. One solution to this might be to have a text file with several hundred -- or even several thousand -- words in it, that Python could quite easily and quickly load into your `Word` class on initialisation of your programme. If the words are saved in a `words.txt` file, and are separated with newlines, you could do it like this:

```
class Word:
    WORDS_FILE = 'words.txt'

    with open(WORDS_FILE, 'r') as f:
        WORDS = tuple(f.read().splitlines())

    # <--- snip --->
```

[Here's a list](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt) of 58,000 words just waiting for you to copy and paste.

Comment: Now using *PyCharm* rather than *Idle* - good tip (though it does gobble up screen space on a little XPS13 - we're travelling at the mo). Your DocString for *Gallows* caused much amusement here :)

Comment: Ha, glad you enjoyed it! Always good to remember to keep coding fun, I think

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if posting as an answer is the right way to do this? Here's the code reworked to take into account suggestions from @Alex Waygood (thanks for good and useful points Alex).

- Running *pycodestyle* did throw up a lot of conflicts with PEP8!
- Swapped ‘ for “ as the string delimiter (seems we’re more likely to
  need to embed a ‘ than a “ within a string).
- Moved everything relating to the command line out of the *hangman*
  module into *main.py*. The *hangman* module can then be, for example,
  used to support a GUI version (next project?). Means saying goodbye
  to the *Gallows* class (and excellent docstring suggestion for it)
- Acted on the suggestion to get the words from a text file but amended
  slightly - multiple topic files for topic focused word lists.
- Reading text files allowed experimenting with exception handling.
  I don’t really get exception handling. If you can predict an exception
  couldn’t you just write normal code to deal with it?
- Program now allows for spaces and hyphens in words/names.
- Adding docstrings comments - a work in progress at the momement. Harder to write than expected, but focuses the mind.
- Repl here: https://replit.com/@scripta/Hangman?v=1

Hangman.py

```
"""
Support for a game of hangman

Classes:
    Word
    Guesses
"""

import random
import sys


class Word:
    """Represents the target word for the game. """

    TOPICS = ("bird", "city", "scientist", "animal")

    def __init__(self):
        """Gets random topic and then a random word from that topic's file."""
        self._topic = random.choice(Word.TOPICS)
        filename = (self._topic+".txt")
        try:
            f = open(filename, "r")
        except OSError:
            print("Cannot open word list " + filename + " unable to continue")
            sys.exit()
        with f:
            WORDS = tuple(f.read().splitlines())
        self._word = random.choice(WORDS)
        self.extract_letters()

    @property
    def word(self):
        return self._word

    @property
    def topic(self):
        return self._topic

    @property
    def letters(self):
        return self._letters

    def extract_letters(self):
        """Extracts unique letters from the word,
           discarding spaces and hyphens."""
        uppercase_word = self._word.upper()
        self._letters = set(uppercase_word)
        self._letters.discard(" ")
        self._letters.discard("-")

    def progress(self, guesses):
        """Creates a string of guessed letters, spaces & hyphens.
           Unguessed letters replaced with underscores."""
        progress_string = ""
        for char in self.word:
            if guesses.guessed(char.upper()):
                progress_string += f" {char} "
            elif char == " ":
                progress_string += "   "
            elif char == "-":
                progress_string += " - "
            else:
                progress_string += " _ "
        return progress_string

    def guessed(self, guesses):
        """Determines if the player has successfully guessed the word."""
        letters_guessed = self._letters.intersection(guesses.guesses_made)
        return letters_guessed == self._letters


class Guesses:
    """Guesses holds all guesses made (right or wrong)."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.guesses_made = set()

    def guessed(self, char):
        """Determines whether a character already been guessed."""
        return char in self.guesses_made

    def record(self, guess):
        """Adds all valid guesses (wrong or right) to the guesses set."""
        self.guesses_made.add(guess)

    def made(self):
        """Creates a comma separated string of letters guessed so far."""
        guesses_list = sorted(self.guesses_made)
        guesses_string = ",".join(guesses_list)
        return guesses_string
```

main.py

```
import hangman

GALLOWS_IMAGES = (" ",
                  "      \n      \n        \n         \n        \n__________",
                  "      \n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |    \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/   \n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/  |\n |      \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |       \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |   |   \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|   \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |      \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  /   \n_|________",
                  " _____\n |/  |\n |   O  \n |  /|\\ \n |  / \\\n_|________",)


def hanged(number_of_bad_guesses):
    return number_of_bad_guesses >= len(GALLOWS_IMAGES) - 1


def draw_gallows(number_of_bad_guesses):
    print(GALLOWS_IMAGES[number_of_bad_guesses])


def display_progress_to_target_word(target_word, guesses):
    print("\n", target_word.progress(guesses))


def display_letters_guessed(guesses):
    print("\nUsed: \n", guesses.made())


def display_topic(target_word):
    print("\nHangman - guess the name of the", target_word.topic)


def get_letter(guesses):
    while True:
        char = input("\nEnter a letter: ")
        char = char.upper()
        if len(char) < 1:
            print("You didn't choose a letter!")
        elif len(char) != 1:
            print("One letter at a time!")
        elif not char.isalpha():
            print("Alphabetic characters only!")
        elif guesses.guessed(char):
            print("You already guessed that letter")
        else:
            break
    return char


def display_status_of_game(target_word, guesses, number_of_bad_guesses):
    display_topic(target_word)
    display_progress_to_target_word(target_word, guesses)
    draw_gallows(number_of_bad_guesses)
    display_letters_guessed(guesses)


def play_game():
    number_of_bad_guesses = 0
    target_word = hangman.Word()
    guesses = hangman.Guesses()
    display_topic(target_word)
    display_progress_to_target_word(target_word, guesses)
    while True:
        guess = get_letter(guesses)
        guesses.record(guess)
        if guess not in target_word.letters:
            number_of_bad_guesses += 1
        display_status_of_game(target_word, guesses, number_of_bad_guesses)
        if target_word.guessed(guesses):
            print("\nYou win, well done")
            break
        if hanged(number_of_bad_guesses):
            print("\nI win. The", target_word.topic, "was:", target_word.word)
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_game()
```

scientist.txt

```
Albert Einstein
Issac Newton
Galileo
Charles Darwin
Copernicus
Aristotle
Niels Bohr
Max Planck
Michael Faraday
```

city.txt

```
Sydney
Los Angeles
Frankfurt
Kuala Lumpur
```

bird.txt

```
blackbird
buzzard
crow
curlew
dunnock
eagle
firecrest
gannet
goldfinch
heron
hobby
house martin
jackdaw
moorhen
nightingale
quail
robin
skylark
song thrush
sparrow
swallow
swift
tern
waxwing
woodpecker
yellowhammer
black-headed gull
```

animal.txt

```
Aardvark
Chimpanzee
Crocodile
Iguana
Squirrel
Walrus
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not just run [black](https://github.com/psf/black) over your code to make the code PEP-8 compliant? I run Black on save to always keep my code formated =)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like *Black* zaps your code into shape, rather than helping embed good habits. Maybe later.

Comment: Good habits is more than just formating. E.g difference between a linter and a formater. I leave the formating to black and focus on getting rid of my linting errors (in contrast to formating errors). Something like flake8 is often used, but I find it to be a little over bearing. Instead turn to a proper editor like VsCode and use pylance =) Something like this in the settings.json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800536/black-formatter-does-not-work-in-vscode-after-installing-anaconda3.

Comment: I've played around with *Black* some more. It picked up one transgression that pycodestyle missed.
-        filename = (self._topic+".txt")
+        filename = self._topic + ".txt"