# Java OOP Hangman - revision (get word in category)

Tags: java, object-oriented, hangman

I've revised the code in the light of comments (the initial post was [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273183/java-oop-hangman)). I've initially just redone the logic to get a random word for the category chosen by the player. I'd appreciate any feedback on that, then I'll revise the rest of it. Main points addressed: separate out GUI code and use streams. I'm sure there's still lots to be done to improve it. You can run it at [replit.com](https://replit.com/@scripta/GetWord#Hangman.java).

Game.java

```
public class Game {

    public static void main (String[] args){
            Word word = new Word();
            String randomWord = word.getWord();
            System.out.println(randomWord);
    }
}
```

Word.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

    public class Word {
    
        private static final String WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY = "wordLists/";
        private static final int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 20;
        private static final int MIN_WORD_LENGTH = 3;
    
        String getWord(){
            String category = category();
            List<String> words = wordsInCategory(category);
            Random generateRandom = new Random();
            int randomIndex = generateRandom.nextInt(words.size());
            String word = words.get(randomIndex);
            return word.trim();
        }
    
        private String category() {
            List<String> filenames = null;
            Path path = Paths.get(WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY);
            try {
                Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(path);
                filenames = stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                                  .map(Path::getFileName)
                                  .map(Path::toString)
                                  .collect(toList());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ErrorReporter.missingCategories();
            }
            CategoryChooser chooser = new CategoryChooser();
            String choice = chooser.chooseCategory(filenames);
            return choice;
        }
    
        private List<String> wordsInCategory(String category){
            List<String> words;
            Path path = Paths.get(WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY +category);
            try  {
                Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);
                words = stream.map(String::toUpperCase)
                              .filter(str -> (str.length() <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH))
                              .filter(str -> (str.length() >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH))
                              .collect(toList());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ErrorReporter.missingCategory();
                words=loadDefaultWords();
            }
            if (words.size()<1){
                ErrorReporter.missingWords();
                words=loadDefaultWords();
            }
            return words;
        }
        private List<String> loadDefaultWords(){
            return List.of("FOXGLOVE", "MICROWAVE","ZOMBIE","PUPPY","RHUBARB","DWARF","BICYCLE",
                "BUZZARD","OWL","CHAFFINCH","KIRIBATI","LIECHTENSTEIN","MOZAMBIQUE");
        }
    
    }
```

CategoryChooser.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class CategoryChooser {

    private String category;

    String chooseCategory(List<String> categoryNames){
        String[] categories = categoryNames.toArray(new String[0]);
        category = categories[0];
        JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<>(categories);
        jComboBox.addActionListener(e -> category = Objects.requireNonNull(jComboBox.getSelectedItem()).toString());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jComboBox, "Word list",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        return category;
    }
}
```

ErrorReporter.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ErrorReporter {

    static void missingCategories(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No word lists found, using default words instead");
    }

    static void missingCategory(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word list missing, using default words instead");
    }

    static void missingWords(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No words found, using default words instead");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code does look good as far as i can tell... you are asking about **OOP** and **Streams** so let's look at them first:

### Streams:

**1) Filter**

you should create a custom filter (aka [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)) for your word-length check

```
Predicate<String> wordLengthPredicate = s -> s.length() <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH && s.length() >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH;
stream.stream().filter(wordLengthPredicate)....; //this is just a stub
```

**2) Mapping**

same applies here, instead of adding mapping after mapping, define a proper [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) that does the job (by the way, why do you do the mapping **twice** where you could do as a one-statement? (`path.getFileName().toString()`) ?

```
Function<Path, String> toCategory = path -> path.getFileName().toString();
stream.stream().map(toCategory)...; //this is just a stub
```

**3) why?**

so why would you separate this during your streams? because you violate the [Integration Operation Segregation Principle (IOSP)](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Integration_Operation_Segregation_Principle_IOSP)!

> IOSP calls for a clear separation:
>
> - Either a method contains exclusively logic, meaning transformations, control structures or API invocations. Then it’s called an Operation.
> - Or a method does not contain any logic but exclusively calls other methods within its code basis. Then it’s called Integration.

### OOP class word

**1) too much responsibilites**
you have very much responsibility in your class:

- loading categories
- loading words of categories
- select a random word of the list
- validate file input

that violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Single_Responsibility_Principle_SRP). take out (at least) the responsibility for loading categories. And best: take out the responsibility for validation the input (see section below)!

**2) naming**

The class `Word` has a weird naming, i had expected at first glance that this class would provide a *Word Model*. Give it a proper name (`WordProvider` or something similar).

the method `category()` also lacks the verb, should be `loadCategory()`

the method `getWord()` should tell more ([Tell - don't ask](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-4-green/#Tell_dont_ask)): `getRandomWord()`

**3) strong coupling**

you have a strong coupling between **category** and **word** - you should get rid of that.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Category category = ... //i hope this gives you an idea of how to release the coupling
    Word word = new Word(category);
    String randomWord = word.getWord();
    System.out.println(randomWord);
}
```

### OOP class CategoryChooser

this class is a GUI class - i was surprised by that. a proper name had made this class less surprising ([Tell, don't ask](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-4-green/#Tell_dont_ask)). Rename it to `CategroyChooserDialog` (or rename the method `chooseCategory()` to `showChooseCategoryDialog()`).

minor issue: you can turn`private String category` into a method variable

### OOP: Sanitize your input

make a class that is responsible for that. your file input is valid, when

- it comes from a defines source,
- when all words match the size constraint and
- when all words are upper case.
- (totally missing in your code: **Encoding**)

provide either files that match these requirements and **don't check** the content or create a Input-Validator, that is responsible for that.

### OOP Utility classes

you mix up static and non-static context for your utility classes:

- `ErrorReporter.missingCategories() //static`
- `new CategoryChooser().chooseCategory(filenames); //non static`

Comment: Thanks for all your points @MartinFrank. I’ve tried to address them all. The revised code is posted here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273399/java-oop-hangman-revision-2-get-word-in-category.

Additionally:

You suggested renaming the class implementing the JOptionPane for choosing the category to make it clear it was a GUI component. I’ve done that, but also made it a subclass of JOptionPane.
On sanitizing the input - haven’t succeeded in checking the character encoding for the word lists. Currently, if I feed it a binary file, it crashes inelegantly! Any pointers?

Comment: i'll have a look, i am interesed in your progress!