# Java OOP Hangman - revision #2 (get word in category)

Tags: java, object-oriented, hangman

This code gets a random word from a word list for a category chosen by the player. The categories are the names of text file containing a list of words. "Words" can contain spaces and hyphens (e.g. "Charles Darwin" counts as a word). Eventually to be incorporated into a Hangman game. The current post is a revision in response to comments / suggested improvements from [Martin Frank](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/109553/martin-frank) and [RoToRa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2035/rotora). The previous post is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273278/java-oop-hangman-revision-get-word-in-category/273301#273301). I'd be grateful for any additional comments. Specifically:

- Was subclassing JOptionPane a good way to go (CategoryDialogue.java)?
- Exception handling
- What's the best way of checking that the file of words is a text
  file? At the moment it crashes if I feed it a binary file.

Overall: style? clarity? You can run it at [replit](https://replit.com/@scripta/Get-word-2#Main.java).

Main.java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        List<String> candidateWords;

        try {
            String category = new CategoryProvider().getCategory();
            candidateWords = new WordList().getWords(category);
        } catch (MissingCategoriesException e){
            candidateWords = new WordList().loadDefaultWords();
        }
        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(candidateWords.size());
        String targetWord = candidateWords.get(randomIndex);
        System.out.println(targetWord);
    }
}
```

CategoryProvider.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class CategoryProvider {

    private Function<Path, String> toCategory = path -> path.getFileName().toString();

    String getCategory() throws MissingCategoriesException  {
        List<String> categories;
        String category;
        Path path = Paths.get(Constants.WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY);
        try {
            Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(path);
            categories = stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                              .map(toCategory)
                              .collect(toList());
            if (categories.size()>0) {
                JOptionPane chooser = new CategoryDialogue(categories);
                category = (String) chooser.getInputValue();
            }else{
                ErrorReporter.missingFiles();
                throw new MissingCategoriesException ("No word lists in directory",null);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorReporter.missingDirectory();
            throw new MissingCategoriesException ("Word lists directory missing",e);
        }
        return category;
    }
}
```

CategoryDialogue.java

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.List;

class CategoryDialogue extends JOptionPane{

    private String category;

    CategoryDialogue(List<String> categoryNames){
        String[] categories = categoryNames.toArray(new String[0]);
        category = categories[0];
        JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<>(categories);
        jComboBox.addActionListener(e -> category = (String) jComboBox.getSelectedItem());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jComboBox, "Word list", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
    public String getInputValue(){
        return category;
    }
}
```

WordList.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class WordList {

    private static final int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 20;
    private static final int MIN_WORD_LENGTH = 3;

    private Predicate<String> wordLengthPredicate =
            s -> s.length() <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH && s.length() >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH;

    List<String> getWords(String category){
        List<String> words;
        try  {
            var path = Paths.get(Constants.WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY +category);
            Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);
            words = stream.map(String::toUpperCase)
                          .filter(wordLengthPredicate)
                          .collect(toList());
            if (words.size()<1){
                ErrorReporter.missingWords();
                words=loadDefaultWords();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorReporter.missingFile();
            words=loadDefaultWords();
    }
        return words;
    }

     List<String> loadDefaultWords(){
        return List.of("FOXGLOVE", "MICROWAVE","ZOMBIE","PUPPY","RHUBARB","DWARF","BICYCLE",
                "BUZZARD","OWL","CHAFFINCH","KIRIBATI","LIECHTENSTEIN","MOZAMBIQUE");
    }
}
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {

    static final String WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY = "wordLists/";

}
```

MissingCategoriesException.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

class MissingCategoriesException extends Exception{

    MissingCategoriesException(String errorMessage, IOException e) {
            super(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

ErrorReporter.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ErrorReporter {

    static void missingFile(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word list file missing, using default words instead");
    }

    static void missingFiles(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No word list files in directory, using default words instead");
    }

    static void missingWords(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No valid words in list, using default words instead");
    }

    static void missingDirectory(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word list directory missing, using default words instead");
    }

    static void notTextFile(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chosen word list file not a text file, using default words instead");
    }

}
```

Sample word list "scientists"

```
Charles Darwin
Max Planck
Albert Einstein
Michael Faraday
Richard Feynmann
Linnaeus
Lavoisier
Aristotle
Marie Curie
Isaac Newton
```

Answer (score 1):

it's nice to see your code developing :-)

picking up your questions:

### Was subclassing JOptionPane a good way to go?

you can choose a more simple JOptionPane usage - see [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Todisplaysadialogwithalistofchoicesinadropdownlistbox.htm) tutorial:

```
String[] choices = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    null, //parent 
    "Choose now...", //title 
    "The Choice of a Lifetime", //message
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
    null, // Use default icon
    choices, // Array of choices
    choices[1] // Initial choice 
);
```

so you don't need to subclass JOptionPane.

### Exception handling

when you have no category for your words you **use a fallback**: default word list. You should use the same approach for categories. if you cannot read the categroies you return the default category (`DEFAULT_CATEGORY`).

with this approach you can totally skip the additional exception (`MissingCategoriesException`)!

that would **reduce complexity**

1. in your `main` method
2. as well as in your `Category` class
3. also in your `WordList` (first statement: `if category.isDefault() return loadDefaultWords();`)

### What's the best way of checking that the [...] file?

well i'm sorry you didn't find the [corresponding question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192770/check-given-file-is-simple-text-file-using-java). my Approach would be to follow the answer from [Andreas Ligios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1654265/andrea-ligios) where he proposes the usage of [`FileTypeDetector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(path);
```

it follows *[RFC 2045: Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Part One: Format of Internet Message Bodies.](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)*

### Overall: style? clarity?

**1) class `Constants`**

well what bothers me at first glance: the class `Constants`. you separate concers, but the `WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY` belongs simply to the `WordList` und should be packed together (as a constante inside the class). This is a code smell named *[Man in the Middle](https://refactoring.guru/smells/middle-man)*

**2) violation of [IOPS](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Integration_Operation_Segregation_Principle_IOSP)** (that would be a BIG BUMMER if you could solve them)

both your methods `String CategoryProvider.getCategory()` and `List<String> WordList.getWords(String category)` violate them. Thats why they look so messy!

again IOSP calls for a clear separation:

- Either a method contains exclusively logic, meaning transformations, control structures or API invocations. Then it’s called an Operation.
- Or a method does not contain any logic but exclusively calls other methods within its code basis. Then it’s called Integration.

this time i'll give you an example. `getWords` is a mere integration method and does NO OPERATION AT ALL!

```
List<String> getWords(String category){
    List<String> words = loadDefaultWords();
    if(category.isDefault()){
        return words;
    }
    
    try{
        File wordDir = getWordDir(category);
        List<String> candidates = loadWordsFromDir(wordDir);
        if(isWordListValid(candidates)){
            words = candidates;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        displayErrors(e);
    }
    return words;
}
```

this example shows how you put all flow logic into a method without using any operation. This method does nothing but call other methods.

**side note**

`loadDefaultWords` is a misleading name, it's just `defaultWords()`.

### feedback

it nice to see your code evolving! keep up that attitude!

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I have learned loads from your comments. Revised version of WordToGuess as a new question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273582/java-oop-hangman-revision-3-wordtoguess. JOptionPane - the code is simpler, but it adds a “Cancel” button. That doesn’t really fit the flow at this point. Exception handling - hopefully cleaner in the new version. I did checkout probeContentType. It just seemed to use the file extension. IOPS does make the code cleaner. How well does the new version meet that? Currently, WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY is used in two classes.

Comment: By the way - I changed to "topic" for a word list, rather than "category"

Comment: probeContentType returned null for my files (that have no extension) and text/plain if it had a txt extension, even if it was a binary file.

Comment: You suggested ditching one exception by defaulting categories (now topics) - I kept it in so that I could report the use of defaults back to the player.