# Java OOP Hangman - revision #3 (WordToGuess)

Tags: java, object-oriented, hangman

This class gets a word to be used in a game of Hangman. The player can select a topic from which a random word is selected. The topic is the name of a text file. For example the text file *scientists* contains words/names such as *Charles Darwin* and *Archimedes*. If for any reason a list of candidate words can't be loaded it falls back to a default list. The rewritten code built on very useful feedback from [Martin Frank](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/109553/martin-frank) and and [RoToRa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2035/rotora) to [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273399/java-oop-hangman-revision-2-get-word-in-category). Rather than post all the changes, I've posted just one class. Any criticisms of the style, clarity or structure gratefully received.

Game.java

```
Game() {
    targetWord = new WordToGuess().getWordToGuess();
    ...
```

WordToGuess.java

```
public class WordToGuess {

  private static final int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 20;
  private static final int MIN_WORD_LENGTH = 3;

  private final String word;

  private final Predicate<String> wordLengthPredicate =
      s -> s.length() <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH && s.length() >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH;

  WordToGuess() {
    List<String> candidateWords = getCandidateWords();
    int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(candidateWords.size());
    word = candidateWords.get(randomIndex);
  }

  String getWordToGuess() {
    return word;
  }

  private List<String> getCandidateWords() {
    List<String> candidateWords = defaultWords();
    try {
      String topic = new TopicProvider().getTopic();
      candidateWords = getWordsInTopic(topic);
    }catch(NoWordsListsException e){
      ErrorReporter.missingFiles();
    }catch (TopicWordsMissingException e){
      ErrorReporter.missingWords();
    } catch (WordListDirectoryMissingException e) {
      ErrorReporter.missingDirectory();
    }
    return candidateWords;
  }

  private List<String> getWordsInTopic(String topic) throws TopicWordsMissingException {
    List<String> candidateWords;
    try {
      Path path = Paths.get(Constants.WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY +topic);
      Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);
      candidateWords = stream.map(String::toUpperCase)
                    .filter(wordLengthPredicate)
                    .collect(toList());
      if (candidateWords.size() < 1) {
        throw new TopicWordsMissingException("The file for that topic contained no words");
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new TopicWordsMissingException("The file for that topic was missing");
    }
    return candidateWords;
  }

  private static List<String> defaultWords(){
    return List.of("FOXGLOVE", "MICROWAVE","ZOMBIE","PUPPY","RHUBARB","DWARF","BICYCLE",
                   "BUZZARD","OWL","CHAFFINCH","KIRIBATI","LIECHTENSTEIN","MOZAMBIQUE");
  }
}
```

Comment: i see [IOSP](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Integration_Operation_Segregation_Principle_IOSP) - very very nice ^_^

Comment: I've updated the post here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273670/java-oop-hangman-revision-4-includes-uml and uploaded the most recent code to GitHub

Comment: https://github.com/salicis/Hangman

Comment: i'll have a look :-)