# Java OOP Hangman revision #4 includes UML

Tags: java, object-oriented, hangman

This is a continuation of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273582/java-oop-hangman-revision-3-wordtoguess). In the game the player chooses a topic and then gets a random word (or words) from that topic to guess.

[image]
I've repartitioned the code into objects several times, without changing the player's experience of the game at all. Some partitionings were clearly better than others. In other cases I wasn't sure. My question is: how do you judge the quality of a partitioning? - preferably, before coding. I'm assuming that some of you use diagrams (UML) in the same way as architects explore different floor plans in their drawings. I've had an attempt at a UML diagram for my code. Can you judge the quality from a diagram like that? I'm struggling a bit to understand UML - so the diagram may be pretty flawed! (hints on how to draw UML welcome).

One thing I wrestled with is, whether to make getting a topic and getting a word list part of Game, or as here, part of getting a word. Maybe it doesn't matter?

You can run it at [Replit.com here.](https://replit.com/@scripta/Hangman-2#Main.java) The code is [here at GitHub](https://github.com/salicis/Hangman). Thanks for their comments to [Martin Frank](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/109553/martin-frank) and and [RoToRa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2035/rotora)

Any additional comments on the detail of the code, or the partitioning into objects, appreciated.

**Ammendment:** Changed `WordToGuess.getWordsInTopic()` to open stream using try with resources:

```
Path path = Paths.get(Constants.WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY +topic);
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)){
  ...
```

[image: uml]
Major classes follow:

Main.java

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main (String[] args){

    Game game = new Game();
  }
}
```

Game.java

```java
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Game {

  private Progress progress;
  private GUI gui;

  Game() {
    String targetWord = new WordToGuess().getWordToGuess();
    progress = new Progress(targetWord);
    JPanel alphabet = new Alphabet(this);
    gui = new GUI(progress.getProgress(),alphabet);
    gui.setVisible(true);
  }

  void recordGuess(char letter) {
    progress.updateProgress(letter);
    gui.showStatus(progress.getNumberOfWrongGuesses(), progress.getProgress());
    if (progress.playerWins()) {
      displayEndGameMessage("Well done, it was "+progress.getTargetWord()+", another game?");
    }
    if (progress.playerLooses()) {
      displayEndGameMessage("Bad luck, it was "+progress.getTargetWord()+", another game?");
    }
  }

  void displayEndGameMessage(String message){
    int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(gui, message, "end", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      GUI oldGUI = gui;
      new Game();
      oldGUI.dispose();
    } else {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

WordToGuess.java

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class WordToGuess {

  private static final int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 20;
  private static final int MIN_WORD_LENGTH = 3;

  private final String word;

  private final Predicate<String> wordLengthPredicate =
      s -> s.length() <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH && s.length() >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH;

  WordToGuess() {
    List<String> candidateWords = getCandidateWords();
    int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(candidateWords.size());
    word = candidateWords.get(randomIndex);
  }

  String getWordToGuess() {
    return word;
  }

  private List<String> getCandidateWords() {
    List<String> candidateWords = defaultWords();
    try {
      String topic = new TopicProvider().getTopic();
      candidateWords = getWordsInTopic(topic);
    }catch(NoWordsListsException e){
      ErrorReporter.missingFiles();
    }catch (TopicWordsMissingException e){
      ErrorReporter.missingWords();
    } catch (WordListDirectoryMissingException e) {
      ErrorReporter.missingDirectory();
    }
    return candidateWords;
  }

  private List<String> getWordsInTopic(String topic) throws TopicWordsMissingException {
    List<String> candidateWords;
    try {
      Path path = Paths.get(Constants.WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY +topic);
      Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);
      candidateWords = stream.map(String::toUpperCase)
                    .filter(wordLengthPredicate)
                    .collect(toList());
      if (candidateWords.size() < 1) {
        throw new TopicWordsMissingException("The file for that topic contained no words");
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new TopicWordsMissingException("The file for that topic was missing");
    }
    return candidateWords;
  }

  private static List<String> defaultWords(){
    return List.of("FOXGLOVE", "MICROWAVE","ZOMBIE","PUPPY","RHUBARB","DWARF","BICYCLE",
                    "BUZZARD","OWL","CHAFFINCH","KIRIBATI","LIECHTENSTEIN","MOZAMBIQUE");
  }
}
```

TopicProvider.java

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class TopicProvider {

  String getTopic() throws NoWordsListsException, WordListDirectoryMissingException {
    List<String> categories = getTopics();
    return getPlayerChoice(categories);
  }

  private List<String> getTopics() throws NoWordsListsException, WordListDirectoryMissingException {
    Path path = Paths.get(Constants.WORD_LIST_DIRECTORY);
    List<String> topics;
    try {
      Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(path);
      topics = stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                          .map(toTopic)
                          .collect(toList());
      if (topics.size() < 1) {
        throw new NoWordsListsException("Word lists missing");
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new WordListDirectoryMissingException("Word lists directory missing");
    }
    return topics;
  }

  private final Function<Path, String> toTopic = path -> path.getFileName().toString();

  private String getPlayerChoice(List<String> Topics){
    return new TopicDialogue().ShowTopicDialogue(Topics);
  }
}
```

TopicDialogue.java

```java
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.List;

class TopicDialogue {

  private String topic;

  String ShowTopicDialogue(List<String> categoryNames){
    String[] categories = categoryNames.toArray(new String[0]);
    topic = categories[0];
    JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<>(categories);
    jComboBox.addActionListener(e -> topic = (String) jComboBox.getSelectedItem());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jComboBox, "Choose a topic", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    return topic;
  }

}
```

Progress.java

```java
public class Progress {

  private static final String placeHolder = "*";
  private final char[] progress;
  private int wrongGuessCount =0;
  private final String targetWord;
  private final int MAX_BAD_GUESSES = 11;

  Progress(String targetWord){
    this.targetWord=targetWord;
    String progressString = targetWord.replaceAll("[A-Z]", placeHolder);
    progress = progressString.toCharArray();
  }

  String getProgress(){
        return new String(progress);
    }

  String getTargetWord(){
        return targetWord;
    }

  boolean playerWins(){
        return !new String(progress).contains(placeHolder);
    }

  boolean playerLooses(){
        return (wrongGuessCount > MAX_BAD_GUESSES);
    }

  int getNumberOfWrongGuesses(){
        return wrongGuessCount;
    }

  void updateProgress(char guess) {
    if (isGoodGuess(guess)) {
      for (int n = 0; n < targetWord.length(); n++) {
        if (targetWord.charAt(n) == guess) {
          progress[n] = guess;
        }
      }
    } else {
      wrongGuessCount++;
    }
}
  boolean isGoodGuess(char guess){
        return targetWord.contains(Character.toString(guess));
    }
}
```

GUI.java

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

  private JLabel progressLabel;
  private GibbetLabel gibbetLabel;

  GUI(String prog, JPanel alphabet) {
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(container);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    gibbetLabel = new GibbetLabel();
    container.add(gibbetLabel);

    progressLabel = new ProgressLabel(prog);
    container.add(progressLabel);

    container.add(alphabet);
    setTitle("Hangman");
    setSize(new Dimension(350, 450));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  void showStatus(int count, String prog){
    progressLabel.setText(prog);
    gibbetLabel.updateGibbetImage(count);
  }

}
```

Alphabet.java

```java
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

class Alphabet extends JPanel{

  Alphabet(Game game){

    for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c){
      JButton button = new JButton(Character.toString(c));
      button.addActionListener(e -> {
        game.recordGuess(e.getActionCommand().charAt(0));
        button.setEnabled(false);
      });
      add(button);
    }
  }
}
```

ProgressLabel.java

```java
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Component;

public class ProgressLabel extends JLabel {

    ProgressLabel(String prog){
        setText(prog);
        setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    }
}
```

GibbetLabel.java

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GibbetLabel extends JLabel {
    private static final int IMAGE_COUNT = 13;
    private ArrayList<File> gibbetImages = new ArrayList<>();

    GibbetLabel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++) {
            try {
                gibbetImages.add(new File("images/" + i + ".png"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(String.valueOf(gibbetImages.get(0))));
        setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    }
    void updateGibbetImage(int count){
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(String.valueOf(gibbetImages.get(count))));
    }
}
```